# How to use unichar array in C# struct with DLLImport of unmanaged C

Tags: c#, struct, dllimport, unichar

I am trying to build a struct in C# to pass to unmanaged C++, I was wondering what is the correct type of variable to use for a `unichar` array in my struct and what it should be marshalled as.

I have already figured this out for an `unsigned char array`

C/C++

```
typedef struct _foo {
    void *fileId;
    unsigned char   fileName[15];
} foo;
```

C#

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
public struct foo
{
   public IntPtr fileId;
   [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 15)]
   public string fileName;
}
```

So if I have the following in C++

```
typedef struct _foo {
    void *fileId;
    unichar fileName[15];   //  UTF-16LE
} foo;
```

What would be the correct struct to use in C#?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Specify the structure as a unicode structure:

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
public struct foo
{
   public IntPtr fileId;
   [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 15)]
   public string fileName;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing the same `struct` would do, but you need to set the `DllImportAttribute.CharSet` property to `Auto` or it will default to `Ansi`. `Unicode` would do too, but unless you are using Windows 98 or Me (no comments) `Auto` will marshal strings as *Unicode*.